# Q: Saxon XQuery Custom Resolver

Tags: java, xquery, saxon

I'm trying to confirm that my implementation for registering Custom Resolvers is correct...
I want the resolver to throw an "Unauthorized" error when a corresponding saxon xquery function is called.

First, I write a custom class along those lines:

```
class CustomURIResolver implements URIResolver{
            public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws XPathException {
                throw new XPathException("Illegal Operation");
            }]
        }
```

and then I set the resolver via the underlying config on the processor:

```
Processor proc = new Processor(false);
// Override SystemURIResolver
net.sf.saxon.Configuration xconfig = proc.getUnderlyingConfiguration();
xconfig.setURIResolver(new CustomURIResolver());
```

Is this reasonable or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `URIResolver` on the `XQueryEvaluator`, not on the `Configuration`.

Also, it depends on what the "corresponding saxon xquery function" is. The URIResolver is used for the `doc()` function, for example, but not for `unparsed-text()`.

Comment: Is it incorrect to use Configuration object?
Looks like I can only set custom URIResolver on XQueryEvaluator while Configuration seems to offer a more general interface to set resolvers.

Comment: Setting it on Configuration works too. But the scope might be more global than you really want, e.g affecting how schema documents are read.

Comment: Thank you so much!